# iOS objc::DenseMap performance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance, ios5

I am working on an iOS 5 project and have run into a severe performance problem, reducing my app to <10fps consistently.  The time profiling tool has identified a call to `objc::DenseMap` which seems to have to do with the retain/release/autorelease system in the Objective-C runtime.  This call is taking a massive portion of processing time and I was wondering if anyone has any pointers for resolving this penalty and/or ways of avoiding this issue.  I suspect it has something to do with the NSMutableArrays, NSMutableSets, and other mutable collections I am using to manage objects per frame.  Any advice or insight into tracking this down and resolving it would be much appreciated.  Below is everything in the trace that looked important or pertinent:

```
Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
1426.0ms    7.2%    1426.0      objc::DenseMap<objc_object*, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<objc_object*>, objc::DenseMapInfo<unsigned long> >::LookupBucketFor(objc_object* const&, std::pair<objc_object*, unsigned long>*&) const
817.0ms    4.1% 0.0      objc::DenseMap<objc_object*, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<objc_object*>, objc::DenseMapInfo<unsigned long> >::FindAndConstruct(objc_object* const&)
817.0ms    4.1% 0.0       _objc_rootRetain
817.0ms    4.1% 0.0        -[NSObject retain]
773.0ms    3.9% 0.0         objc_retain
28.0ms    0.1%  0.0         -[NSMutableArray removeObject:]
11.0ms    0.0%  0.0         CFRetain
580.0ms    2.9% 0.0      objc::DenseMap<objc_object*, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<objc_object*>, objc::DenseMapInfo<unsigned long> >::find(objc_object* const&)
580.0ms    2.9% 0.0       _objc_rootReleaseWasZero
580.0ms    2.9% 0.0        _objc_rootRelease
562.0ms    2.8% 0.0         objc_release
1.0ms    0.0%   0.0         CFRelease
19.0ms    0.0%  0.0      objc::DenseMap<objc_object*, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<objc_object*>, objc::DenseMapInfo<unsigned long> >::grow(unsigned int)
19.0ms    0.0%  0.0       objc::DenseMap<objc_object*, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<objc_object*>, objc::DenseMapInfo<unsigned long> >::InsertIntoBucket(objc_object* const&, unsigned long const&, std::pair<objc_object*, unsigned long>*)
19.0ms    0.0%  0.0        objc::DenseMap<objc_object*, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<objc_object*>, objc::DenseMapInfo<unsigned long> >::FindAndConstruct(objc_object* const&)
19.0ms    0.0%  0.0         _objc_rootRetain
19.0ms    0.0%  0.0          -[NSObject retain]
15.0ms    0.0%  0.0           objc_retain
4.0ms    0.0%   0.0           -[NSMutableArray removeObject:]
5.0ms    0.0%   0.0      _objc_rootRetain
5.0ms    0.0%   0.0       -[NSObject retain]
4.0ms    0.0%   0.0        objc_retain
3.0ms    0.0%   0.0         objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
1.0ms    0.0%   0.0        -[NSMutableArray removeObject:]
3.0ms    0.0%   0.0      _objc_rootReleaseWasZero
3.0ms    0.0%   0.0       _objc_rootRelease
3.0ms    0.0%   0.0        objc_release
2.0ms    0.0%   0.0      objc::DenseMap<objc_object*, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<objc_object*>, objc::DenseMapInfo<unsigned long> >::erase(objc_object* const&)
2.0ms    0.0%   0.0       objc_clear_deallocating
2.0ms    0.0%   0.0        objc_destructInstance
2.0ms    0.0%   0.0         CFRelease
```

Comment: Its hard to say without more context. Would you be able to post the entire trace from instruments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter out the system libraries from the performance analysis and see what that indicates.   You are looking at the wrong end of the stack.

Your code, typically, is a relatively thin veneer that glues together the system frameworks in whatever way is necessary for you to create your specific app.   A performance problem like this most often indicates that your apps implementation is algorithmically non-performant;  maybe you are re-cacluating stuff too often, maybe you are emptying/filling collections when you could be using a cache, etc...

Comment: Allow me to better explain what I am attempting: every frame the player moves the view of the camera, the render list (NSMutableArray) is emptied and each objects is tested to see whether is it still visible or not, placing it into the render list.  I'm beginning to believe that the process of adding/removing objects from the NSMutableArray is an expensive process and needs some re-evaluation.  Does that sound right?

Comment: How many objects do you have in the render list?  Yes, in general, taking objects in/out of the render list entirely, instead of just moving 'em, will be expensive.   It isn't so much that the add/remove from the mutable array is expensive, it is that it is expensive when you are doing 100s of objects potentially dozens+ times/second!  It adds up.

Comment: My test harness has shown that, indeed, emptying and re-adding is extremely time intensive.  I have found that moving to a `NSMutableSet` and checking for inclusion before acting yields a considerably faster result.  Thanks for the help!